# Copying/pasting specific files in batch from one folder to another

Tags: python

I'am really new to this python scripting thing, but  pretty sure, that there is the way to copy files from one folder (via given path in .txt file) to another.
 
[there would be directly path to the folder, which contains photo files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZaeq.png)

I'am working with huge amounts of photos, which contains gps metadata (so i need not to lose it). 
Really apreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What would be a format of paths in the .txt file? How does it define source and destination?

Comment: [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) sounds like the function you're looking for.

Comment: I've tried shutil, but for me it worked only on a single file. How to define .txt file as path for multiple files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short and simple solution:

```py
import shutil
import os

# replace file_list.txt with your files
file_list = open("file_list.txt", "r")
# replace my_dir with your copy dir
copy_dir = "my_dir"

for f in file_list.read().splitlines():
    print(f"copying file: {f}")
    shutil.copyfile(f, f"{copy_dir}/{os.path.split(f)[1]}")

file_list.close()
print("done")
```

It loops over all the files in the file list, and copies them. It should be fast enough.

Comment: Thank You Xilpex, you saved my night big time !